# Failed 'Get manifest' status within Postman

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am trying to create web page for my Revit file from following tutorial 
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O4Td3F4IjA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysI8F.jpg)

I am getting following error at Get Mainfest

[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysI8F.jpg)

Other things are working fine.

It seems all the viewers are facing similar problem.

Looking forward to an update so that I can successfully view my test project on my web page.

Comment: Please cut and paste the piece of code with a problem as well as the  error message into your question. Links are not very useful and turn many potential helpers away.

Answer (score 0):

By decoding your URN `dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c2lrcmFuZ2hkYXQyMDE3LTA1LTI4L1Byb2plY3QxLnJ2dA`, it seems that your source file format is RVT.

After watching the unofficial tutorial video, I found there is one incorrect parameter in the translation job configuration. The `compressedUrn` parameter should be `false` since RVT is not a compressed format and this parameter is for the ZIP file. You must have to correct your Job Configuration body like this:

```
{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c2lrcmFuZ2hkYXQyMDE3LTA1LTI4L1Byb2plY3QxLnJ2dA",
     "compressedUrn": false,
     "rootFilename": "Project1.rvt"
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

And if the target model is not a ZIP format, you can simplify it:

```
{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c2lrcmFuZ2hkYXQyMDE3LTA1LTI4L1Byb2plY3QxLnJ2dA"
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

Besides, you might have to delete the failed translation result via calling [DELETE :urn/manifest](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/) or pass `x-ads-force: true` in to request header of the API [POST job](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) call.

Hope it helps.